# Why do I need to add third party senders to my domain's SPF record?

Tags: spf

It's my understanding that SPF works on the envelope sender/return-path/RFC5321.MailFrom domain. We use a third party email service called Campaign Monitor and their domain has the required SPF record. Emails that are sent have their domain as the envelope sender/return path.

I'm now reading this from Google:

> The SPF record for your domain should reference all email senders for your domain. If third-party senders aren't included in your SPF record, messages from these senders are more likely to be marked as spam.

Source: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126

And this from Campaign Monitor:

> However, it is an optional but recommended step to include our servers in an SPF record for your domain.

Source: https://help.campaignmonitor.com/email-authentication#spf

Suggestion that "some local anti-spam services" may require this:

> While we handle SPF for you, some anti-spam services on your local network may be particularly strict, requiring our domain to be added to your own existing SPF record

Source: https://help.campaignmonitor.com/allowlist-campaign-monitors-addresses#spf

Possibly relevant article:

> Another day, another ESP telling a client to publish a SPF include for the wrong domain.

Source: https://wordtothewise.com/2022/06/stop-with-the-incorrect-spf-advice/

Why are we being told that we should add their domains to our own domain's SPF record? Who are these "anti-spam" services that aren't following the rules?

Comment: Are you sure that they are using their own domain, everything on their points to me that you guys only use their platform with your own domain.

Comment: Positive. The smtp.mailfrom in the message headers is an address @cmail20.com which belongs to Campaign Monitor

Answer (score 0):

> It's my understanding that SPF works on the envelope sender/return-path/RFC5321.MailFrom domain. ... Emails that are sent have their domain as the envelope sender/return path

Yes, technically you don't need it, however:

1. There are many implementations of SPF validation, at least some of them may not be compliant.
2. When your envelope sender does not match the From header, most providers will increase your spam score (hence 1 may be deliberate)

> We use a third party email service called Campaign Monitor...Emails that are sent have their domain as the envelope sender/return path

Hmmmm. Although I imagine this will simplify capturing bounce stats.

Comment: I don't see how point 2 is relevant. Google stipulating the requirement in their "2024 email sender guidelines" feels like more than pandering to non-compliant filters.

Comment: Google only make rules for google. Not the entire internet. As far as email is concerned, most people make up their own.

Comment: The 2024 sender requirements are a collaboration between the major players, including Google and Yahoo

Comment: You are conflating Google's policy, other operators policy and rfc7208.

Comment: Just trying to understand why ESPs are seemingly giving bad advice as to where to publish SPF records and indeed if this is not bad advice, why. Ultimately do I need to liaise with my clients and get new SPF records added as a result of "new" requirements being touted by Google and Yahoo.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any ESPs that are increasing SPAM score based solely on SPF alignment mismatch. Many ESPs check for DMARC results, even if no DMARC record has been published (composite authentication as Microsoft calls it). SPF domain does not need to align if you have DKIM authentication. However, if you fail to authenticate on both SPF and DKIM checks, aligned to the FROM domain, your emails' SPAM score will take a hit.